# authentication proxy with selenium C# 2020

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

This is an old problem but I can't resolve it.

I created a chrome extension or Proxy auto auth.crx but it's too old.
I used AutoIt but it has not resolved my problem.

I saw the link [Setting a proxy for Chrome Driver in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730306/setting-a-proxy-for-chrome-driver-in-selenium/27740556#27740556)
but it doesn't run with HTTP or HTTPS.

```
proxy.SocksUserName = "username";
proxy.SocksPassword = "password";
```

How to use authenticated proxy in C#?

Comment: What is your proxy server's vendor i tried adding user name password in PAC file but it seems this is not supported for all proxies it depends on vendor

Comment: I think the best answer is here : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68157236/10203981](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68157236/10203981)